# Confusing use of plain copula （だ should be だった?）

Tags: copula

I am reading Kanon, I will first give the context:

> 大体{だいたい｝、いつからこの家｛いえ｝の朝食｛ちょうしょく｝は和風｛わふう｝になったんだ…
>   [Generally,] Since when did we start eating Japanese food for breakfast...

The main character then narrates:

> 昨日｛きのう｝までは間違いなく｛まちがいなく｝、トーストにゆで卵｛たまご｝だったはずだ
>   Until yesterday, I have unmistakable expectation that it was toast and boiled eggs

If the expectation was until yesterday, should it not be 「だったはずだった」? He surely no longer has the expectation since he has just had his expectation contradicted. My belief is either I am confused at what the copulae are referring to, or 「までは」 forces the rest of sentence into the past (so the plain copula is present tense... in the past... (time travel tense trouble))

Comment: This is some strange sentence.   It was western food  until yesterday, but only today is japanese food. However "since when ~" is clearly today. To say so, it needs some days that recent breakfast was sometimes japanese food.

Comment: This is false of translation. Ubz is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it make more sense to you if I reorganize your translated sentence like this?

> I have unmistakable expectation that **it was toast and eggs until yesterday**.

The way I see it, getting something else today doesn't contradict his strong belief that *before* today it was always toast and eggs. He still has that belief (not sure if "expectation" is an appropriate word here, I think that's taking things too literally).

Comment: I agree "expectation" isn't the right word, although the purpose of this question isn't about a natural translation. I'd say something like "I could have sworn that..."

Comment: Or "Undoubtedly breakfast was toast and boiled eggs."

Answer (score 3):

「昨日までは**間違いなく**トーストにゆで卵**だったはず**だ」 is like 「（私の記憶では）昨日までは**絶対に**トーストにゆで卵**だった**」, "I'm sure it was toast and boiled eggs / It must have been toast and boiled eggs until yesterday (as far as I can remember)".

Compare:

> 「XX**だったはず**だ」 -- "it **must have been** XX" "I **am** sure it **was** XX"
>   vs　
>   「XXの**はずだった**」 -- "it should have been XX" "it was supposed to be XX"

---

By the way, the だいたい means そもそも, "to begin with" or "in the first place", not "generally". See [definition #2⃣-2 of 「だいたい」 in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/133823/meaning/m0u/): 「もとはと言えば。そもそも。『だいたい言い出したのは君だよ』」

(And, as you might have already noticed, the いつから～～なったんだ here is a rhetorical question (修辞疑問文) showing the speaker's dissatisfaction or irritation, not a genuine question expecting an answer.)

Comment: +1 Accurate, concise and informative!

Comment: Just to paraphrase to make sure I have learned from my mistake;
If はず or similar noun (e.g. つもり) is used with a past tense copula, the subject no longer has the はず/つもり/etc.. (they had the はず/つもり, which was subsequently dashed).

Answer (score 1):

### 筈{はず}だ is Expressing his *Current* Expectation

If you remove はずだ this sentence only states a fact, as if the speaker is explaining ***the situation***:

> 昨日までは間違いなく、トーストにゆで卵**だった**。

```
Until yesterday it was always toast and boiled eggs.
```

By adding 筈{はず}だ it sounds as if the speaking is explaining ***his expectation***:

> 昨日までは間違いなく、トーストにゆで卵だった**はずだ**。
>
> Until yesterday it was always ***supposed to be*** toast and boiled eggs.  (so what happened?)